# How to print the slice of pointers to get the values instead of their address without iteration at go?

Tags: go, slice

This kind output required for debugging purpose.
To get actual value of slice of pointers, every time a iteration is getting required.

Is there any way, we can directly have the value instead of the address of each item present at slice using simple fmt.printf()?

Here is a code snippet :
https://play.golang.org/p/bQ5vWTlKZmV

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type user struct {
    userID int
    name   string
    email  string
}

func main() {
    var users []*user
    addUsers(users)
}

func addUsers(users []*user) {
    users = append(users, &user{userID: 1, name: "cooluser1", email: "cool.user1@gmail.com"})
    users = append(users, &user{userID: 2, name: "cooluser2", email: "cool.user2@gmail.com"})
    printUsers(users)
    printEachUser(users)

}

func printUsers(users []*user) {
    fmt.Printf("users at slice %v \n", users)
}

func printEachUser(users []*user) {
    for index, u := range users {
        fmt.Printf("user at user[%d] is : %v \n", index, *u)
    }
}
```

At above code, if I am printing the slice directly by fmt.printf , I get only the address of the values instead of actual value itself.

output : `users at slice [0x442260 0x442280]`

To read to the values always, i have to call `func` like `printEachUser` to iterate the slice and get the appropriate value .

output:
`user at user[0] is : {1 cooluser1 cool.user1@gmail.com}`
`user at user[1] is : {2 cooluser2 cool.user2@gmail.com}`

Is there any way, we can read the values inside the slice of pointers using `fmt.printf` and get value directly like below ?

`users at slice [&{1 cooluser1 cool.user1@gmail.com} , &{2 cooluser2 cool.user2@gmail.com}]`

Comment: No, there's no way without iteration. In fact, there's no way to print the values without iteration, too--it's just that `fmt` handles that iteration for you. But there are some libraries that will do such iteration for you. [spew](https://godoc.org/github.com/davecgh/go-spew/spew) might be one to consider.

Comment: oh yeah!. `fmt` takes care of the iteration.
But, instead of depending on some other package, don't you think implementing `fmt.Stringer` would be a wiser choice ? @Flimzy

Comment: Sure, implementing `fmt.Stringer` would work. Which is a better choice depends on your goals.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> This kind output required for debugging purpose.
>
> Is there any way, we can read the values inside the slice of pointers
>   using `fmt.Printf` and get value directly like below ?
>
> ```
> users []*user
> fmt.Printf("users at slice %v \n", users)
>
> users at slice [&{1 cooluser1 cool.user1@gmail.com}, &{2 cooluser2 cool.user2@gmail.com}]
> ```

---

> [Package fmt](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/)
>
> `import "fmt"`
>
> [type Stringer](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Stringer)
>
> Stringer is implemented by any value that has a String method, which
>   defines the “native” format for that value. The String method is used
>   to print values passed as an operand to any format that accepts a
>   string or to an unformatted printer such as Print.
>
> ```
> type Stringer interface {
>         String() string
> }
> ```

---

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type user struct {
    userID int
    name   string
    email  string
}

type users []*user

func (users users) String() string {
    s := "["
    for i, user := range users {
        if i > 0 {
            s += ", "
        }
        s += fmt.Sprintf("%v", user)
    }
    return s + "]"
}

func addUsers(users users) {
    users = append(users, &user{userID: 1, name: "cooluser1", email: "cool.user1@gmail.com"})
    users = append(users, &user{userID: 2, name: "cooluser2", email: "cool.user2@gmail.com"})

    fmt.Printf("users at slice %v \n", users)
}

func main() {
    var users users
    addUsers(users)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/vDmdiKQOpqD

Output:

```
users at slice [&{1 cooluser1 cool.user1@gmail.com}, &{2 cooluser2 cool.user2@gmail.com}]
```

Comment: this is what, i was looking ,for by implementing the `fmt.Stringer` interface, but for string concatenation, `strings.Builder` will be better instead of `+`

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just define (*User).String() instead of users.String()?

Comment: This still uses iteration, though a bit indirectly

Answer (score 4):

Code : https://play.golang.org/p/rBzVZlovmEc

Output :

> users at slice [{1 cooluser1 cool.user1@gmail.com} {2 cooluser2
>   cool.user2@gmail.com}]

Using stringers you can achive it.

Refer: https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Stringer

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type user struct {
    userID int
    name   string
    email  string
}

func (t user) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("{%v %v %v}", t.userID, t.name, t.email)
}

func main() {
    var users []*user
    addUsers(users)
}

func addUsers(users []*user) {
    users = append(users, &user{userID: 1, name: "cooluser1", email: "cool.user1@gmail.com"})
    users = append(users, &user{userID: 2, name: "cooluser2", email: "cool.user2@gmail.com"})
    printUsers(users)
}

func printUsers(users []*user) {
    fmt.Printf("users at slice %v \n", users)
}
```

**You need not apply stringer to users i.e []*users instead if you do it just for a single user it'll work fine. Also it reduces down the string operations you need to do manually making your code elegant.**

Answer (score 3):

You can use `spew`

`go get -u github.com/davecgh/go-spew/spew`

```
func spewDump(users []*user) {
    _, err := spew.Printf("%v", users)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error while spew print", err)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[<*>{1 cooluser1 cool.user1@gmail.com} <*>{2 cooluser2 cool.user2@gmail.com}]
```

Comment: I'd suggest another fork that is updated more frequently: https://github.com/use-go/spew